# How to create a Purchase Order form in JS

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm new to this forum and new to JS as well. I am trying to make a purchase order form for a site I'm creating. Basically I need it to add the total of the items I select and then send the order. However, I get various errors. The first is when I ran the JS through a JS lint, then the second one is showing an error on line 111 of my code. Also, each one of the drop down values comes up as "undefined" an it doesn't calculate the total. Again, I'm very new to JavaScript so I'm not really sure how to go about fixing this problem so I can get this working. Any advice or help would be great! Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css"> 

</style>

<br/ >
<div align="center">
<img src="navBar.jpg" width="1257" height="96" alt="Navigation Bar" usemap="#navBar" 
style="box-shadow: -20px -20px 15px #0099FF, 20px 20px 15px #00FF00" />
        <map name="navBar" id="navBar">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,1,206,95" href="northAmerica.html" alt="Home Page" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="244,0,568,95" href="worldMap.html" alt="Animal Map" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="601,0,835,95" href="purchaseForm.html" alt="Store" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="876,0,1256,95" href="zooSurvey.html" alt="Take a Survey!" />
        </map>
</div>
<br/ >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css" />

<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
var souvenirs = [Tiger, bobcat, elephant, penguin];


var Tiger = document.getElementById("Tiger_price");
var Tigerprice = parseFloat(Tiger, 10);
var tigerNew = Tigerprice.value;

var bobcat = document.getElementById("bobcat_price");
var bobcatprice = parseFloat(bobcat, 10);
var bobcatNew = bobcatprice.value;

var elephant = document.getElementById("elephant_price");
var elephantprice = parseFloat(elephant, 10);
var elephantNew = elephantprice.value;

var penguin = document.getElementById("penguin_price");
var penguinprice = parseFloat(penguin, 10);
var penguinNew = penguinprice.value;

window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
};

function validate() {
var result = true;

var namefield = document.getElementById("yourname");
var nameerr = document.getElementById("nameerr");
var namefieldRE = /^[\w ]+$/;

var emailfield = document.getElementById("youremail");
var emailerr = document.getElementById("emailerr");



var emailfieldRE = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/ ;

if(!namefield.value.match(namefieldRE)){
nameerr.innerHTML = "Please fill in your name";
nameerr.style.color = "#ff0000";
result = false;
}
else{
nameerr.innerHTML = "";
result = true;
}

if(!emailfield.value.match(emailfieldRE)){
emailerr.innerHTML = "Please fill in your email";
emailerr.style.color = "#ff0000";
result = false;
}
else{
emailerr.innerHTML = "";
result = true;
}

return result;

}


function resetTotals() {
var total = 0.0;
for (souvenirs in souvenirs) {
var subtotal = souvenirs[souvenirs] + "_subtotal";
document.getElementById(subtotal).innerHTML = "0.00";
}
output = document.getElementById("finaltotal");
output.innerHTML = "0.00";
}

function doTotals() {
alert();




for (souvenirs in souvenirs) {


var tigerselectedvalue = document.souvenirsorderform.tiger_quantity.value;
var bobcatselectedvalue = document.souvenirsorderform.bobcat_quantity.value;
var elephantselectedvalue = document.souvenirsorderform.elephant_quantity.value;
var penguinselectedvalue = document.souvenirsorderform.penguin_quantity.value;


document.getElementByID(souvenirs[souvenirs] + "_subtotal") = (souvenirs[souvenirs] + "price") * (souvenirs[souvenirs] + "selectedvalue");


var subtotal = souvenirs[souvenirs] + "_subtotal";
document.getElementById(subtotal).innerHTML = "0.00";
}

output = document.getElementById("finaltotal");
output.innerHTML = total.toFixed(2);
}

if (document.getElementById) {
window.onload = setup;
}

function setup() {
var lastCol = document.getElementById("subtotal_header");

var theForm = document.getElementById("souvenirsorderform");

var amounts = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
amounts[i].onchange = doTotals;
}

theForm.onsubmit = "validate";
theForm.onreset = "resetTotals";
}
</script>
<title>ITS 110 Zoo: Gift Shop</title>
</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="logoZoo.gif" width="280" height="224" alt="Home Page" usemap="#logoZoo" style="border:none" />
<map name="logoZoo" id="logoZoo">
                <area shape="circle" coords="141,114,120" href="northAmerica.html" alt="Home Page" />
        </map>
</td>
<td>
<h1>Purchase&nbsp;</h1>
</td>
<td>
<h1>some&nbsp;</h1>
</td>
<td>
<h1>souvenirs!</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>

<p><b>Don't leave our site without getting your very own ITS110 Zoo souvenirs!
<br/ >
Once you've placed your order, we'll ship your items to the zoo so they're ready when you come for a visit- or we will
send it directly to your home! </b></p>
<br/ >

<h2 style="font-size:24Pt"><b>Place your order:</b></h2>

<form method="post" action="#" name="souvenirsorderform" id="souvenirsorderform" onsubmit="returnvalidate()">

<table>



<tr>
<td><label for="Tiger_quantity"><b>Tiger Plush</b></label></td>
<td><img src="tigerplush.gif" width="200" height="200"/></img></td>
<td>$3<input type="hidden" id="Tiger_price" value="3.00"><br/ >
<select id="Tiger_quantity" name="Tiger_quantity" size="1">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="Tiger_subtotal"></td>
<td><label for="bobcat_quantity"><b>Monkey Plush</b></label></td>
<td><img src="monkey.gif" width="200" height="200"/></img></td>
<td>$3.50<input type="hidden" id="bobcat_price" value="3.50">
<select id="bobcat_quantity" name="bobcat_quantity" size="1"><br/ >
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="bobcat_subtotal"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="Elephant_quantity"><b>Elephant Shirt</b></label></td>
<td><img src="shirt.gif" width="200" height="200"/></img></td>
<td>$12<input type="hidden" id="elephant_price" value="12.00">
<select id="elephant_quantity" name="elephant_quantity" size="1"><br/ >
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="elephant_subtotal"></td>
<td><label for="penguin_quantity"><b>Penguin Shirt</b></label></td>
<td><img src="penshirt.gif" width="200" height="200" /></img></td>
<td>$12<input type="hidden" id="penguin_price" value="12.00"><br/ >
<select id="penguin_quantity" name="penguin_quantity" size="1">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="penguin_subtotal"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="tablefoot"><td>Total:</td><td colspan="2" id="totalerr"><td id="finaltotal"></td></tr>

</table>

<p><b><label for="yourname">Your Full Name:</label>
<input name="yourname" id="yourname" type="text">
<span id="nameerr"></span></b></p>
<p><b><label for="youremail">Your E-Mail Address to Confirm the Order:</label>
<input name="youremail" id="youremail" type="text">
<span id="emailerr"></span></b></p>

<div><button id="submit" type="submit">Place Order</button><button id="reset" type="reset">Clear Order</button></div>
<br/ >
</form>

</body>
</center>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reset form yourself. `<input id="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Order"/>` does it for you.  If you call `alert()`, it shows **undefined** (it's normal). 
 You tried to find DOM element before DOM ready event fired. 
`var Tiger = document.getElementById("Tiger_price");` 
 If you really want to do it, do it when document ready event fired. 
 And always try to use small letters for html element attirbutes. For example: `id="tiger_subtotal"`. 
 I hope this helps. I checked and it's working:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css"> 

</style>

<br/ >
<div align="center">
<img src="navBar.jpg" width="1257" height="96" alt="Navigation Bar" usemap="#navBar" 
style="box-shadow: -20px -20px 15px #0099FF, 20px 20px 15px #00FF00" />
        <map name="navBar" id="navBar">
                <area shape="rect" coords="0,1,206,95" href="northAmerica.html" alt="Home Page" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="244,0,568,95" href="worldMap.html" alt="Animal Map" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="601,0,835,95" href="purchaseForm.html" alt="Store" />
                <area shape="rect" coords="876,0,1256,95" href="zooSurvey.html" alt="Take a Survey!" />
        </map>
</div>
<br/ >

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css" />

<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sheet.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onerror = function(msg, url, linenumber) {
    alert('Error message: '+msg+'\nURL: '+url+'\nLine Number: '+linenumber);
    return true;
};

function validate() {
    var result = true;

    var namefield = document.getElementById("yourname");
    var nameerr = document.getElementById("nameerr");
    var namefieldRE = /^[\w ]+$/;

    var emailfield = document.getElementById("youremail");
    var emailerr = document.getElementById("emailerr");

    var emailfieldRE = /^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/ ;

    if(!namefield.value.match(namefieldRE)){
        nameerr.innerHTML = "Please fill in your name";
        nameerr.style.color = "#ff0000";
        result = false;
    } else{
        nameerr.innerHTML = "";
        result = true;
    }

    if (!emailfield.value.match(emailfieldRE)){
        emailerr.innerHTML = "Please fill in your email";
        emailerr.style.color = "#ff0000";
        result = false;
    } else{
        emailerr.innerHTML = "";
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

function doTotals() {
    var animals = ['Tiger_', 'bobcat_', 'elephant_', 'penguin_'];
    var priceStr = 'price';
    var quantityStr = 'quantity';
    var subtotalStr = 'subtotal';
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
        var price = document.getElementById(animals[i] + priceStr).value;
        var quantity = document.getElementById(animals[i] + quantityStr).value;
        document.getElementById(animals[i] + subtotalStr)
            .innerHTML = parseInt(price) * parseInt(quantity);
        total += price * quantity;
    }
    document.getElementById("finaltotal").innerHTML = total;
}

function setup() {
    var lastCol = document.getElementById("subtotal_header");

    var theForm = document.getElementById("souvenirsorderform");

    var amounts = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
    for(var i = 0; i < amounts.length; i++){
        amounts[i].onchange = doTotals;
    }

    theForm.onsubmit = validate;
}

window.onload = setup;

</script>
<title>ITS 110 Zoo: Gift Shop</title>
</head>

<body>

<div align="center">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="logoZoo.gif" width="280" height="224" alt="Home Page" usemap="#logoZoo" style="border:none" />
<map name="logoZoo" id="logoZoo">
                <area shape="circle" coords="141,114,120" href="northAmerica.html" alt="Home Page" />
        </map>
</td>
<td>
<h1>Purchase&nbsp;</h1>
</td>
<td>
<h1>some&nbsp;</h1>
</td>
<td>
<h1>souvenirs!</h1>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div>

<p><b>Don't leave our site without getting your very own ITS110 Zoo souvenirs!
<br/ >
Once you've placed your order, we'll ship your items to the zoo so they're ready when you come for a visit- or we will
send it directly to your home! </b></p>
<br/ >

<h2 style="font-size:24Pt"><b>Place your order:</b></h2>

<form method="post" action="#" name="souvenirsorderform" id="souvenirsorderform" onsubmit="return validate()">

<table>

<tr>
<td><label for="Tiger_quantity"><b>Tiger Plush</b></label></td>
<td><img src="tigerplush.gif" width="200" height="200"/></img></td>
<td>$3<input type="hidden" id="Tiger_price" value="3.00"><br/>
<select id="Tiger_quantity" name="Tiger_quantity" size="1">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="Tiger_subtotal"></td>
<td><label for="bobcat_quantity"><b>Monkey Plush</b></label></td>
<td><img src="monkey.gif" width="200" height="200"/></img></td>
<td>$3.50<input type="hidden" id="bobcat_price" value="3.50">
<select id="bobcat_quantity" name="bobcat_quantity" size="1"><br/ >
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="bobcat_subtotal"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><label for="Elephant_quantity"><b>Elephant Shirt</b></label></td>
<td><img src="shirt.gif" width="200" height="200"/></img></td>
<td>$12<input type="hidden" id="elephant_price" value="12.00">
<select id="elephant_quantity" name="elephant_quantity" size="1"><br/ >
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="elephant_subtotal"></td>
<td><label for="penguin_quantity"><b>Penguin Shirt</b></label></td>
<td><img src="penshirt.gif" width="200" height="200" /></img></td>
<td>$12<input type="hidden" id="penguin_price" value="12.00"><br/ >
<select id="penguin_quantity" name="penguin_quantity" size="1">
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="0" selected>0</option>
</select>
</td>
<td id="penguin_subtotal"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="tablefoot"><td>Total:</td><td colspan="2" id="totalerr"><td id="finaltotal"></td></tr>

</table>

<p><b><label for="yourname">Your Full Name:</label>
<input name="yourname" id="yourname" type="text">
<span id="nameerr"></span></b></p>
<p><b><label for="youremail">Your E-Mail Address to Confirm the Order:</label>
<input name="youremail" id="youremail" type="text">
<span id="emailerr"></span></b></p>

<div><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Place Order"/>
<input id="reset" type="reset" value="Clear Order"/>
<br/ >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```